# Using Plugin > Map Creator > Set Layer CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am using map creator and I would like to permanently set the layer CRS value. I place multiple maps within one project on QGIS, and I have to manually set the CRS value each time a new layer is created.

It would make my day easier if the maps that I create show up automatically instead of me having to go back and set the CRS value each time.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: My project properties are set; WGS 84 / UTM zone 15N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the layers you're adding all in the same CRS? If you have reproject on the fly enabled this might not be obvious. Test some layers using the reproject tool in the toolbox, it'll tell you what CRS the layer is actually in.

Also have you checked the default option in your version of QGIS:
[image]

Comment: All layers are in the same CRS and project OTF for CRS Transformations is enabled. I am somewhat green with qgis, where do I find reproject? I also have 2.18.28 download and not 3.6 due to scripting capabilities.

Comment: The reproject function is found in the Processing Toolbox. The Toolbox may not be visible on your installation so you need to open that up first from the main menu bar at the top of the screen. Once it's open use the search facility, type in "repro" and it'll show a list of similar functions. The native Qgis one is fine and you can select individual layers in the drop down box, this also shows the actual projection for each layer, rather than what you've assumed it to be. I hope that helps.